# Программно вставить символ в PasswordBox в позицию каретки

Tags: c#, wpf, input

Дорого времени суток!
Я пишу WPF контрол экранной клавиатуры. У нее должен быть режим пароля. Реализовывать этот режим я собрался с помощью PasswordBox. И в ходе реализации возникла проблема: если пользователь в процессе ввода пароля решит переместить каретку в любое место, кроме конца строки, то ввод из позиции каретки невозможен, поскольку ее положение в PasswordBox никак не отслеживается. Проблему удаления символа из любого места помогли решить команды `EditingCommands`, а вот со вставкой беда. Есть ли какие-либо вариаты ввода символов с форматом типа `SomeClass.InsertSymbolInCaretPosition(string symbol, IInputElement myPasswordBox)` либо вообще иные выходы из ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, в ходе размышлений пришел к такому костыльному варианту:

Метод, по кнопке добавляющий символ в строку, выглядит так:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText("s");
passwordBox.Paste();
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear();
```

В итоге, получаем копирование нужного символа, которое происходит автоматически в позицию каретки. Для нужд экранной клавиатуры этого вполне хватает.

Comment: А то что вы затираете содержимое буфера обмена — норм? Пользователь будет удивлен...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это костыль. Также система в которой он будет работать весьма и весьма ограничена в правах и возможностях. Копирование пользователем в буфер обмена в ней закрыто.